# Mail task config (activiti rest)

Tags: rest, email, gmail, task, activiti

I tried to configure mail task with activiti rest, I modify the activiti-custom-context.xml file and the engine.properties file in the following way:

## activiti-custom-context.xml

```
<property name="mailServerHost" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
<property name="mailServerPort" value="465"/>
<property name="mailServerUseTLS" value="false"/>
<property name="mailServerUseSSL" value="true"/>
<property name="mailServerDefaultFrom" value="myadress@gmail.com"/>
<property name="mailServerUsername" value="myadress@gmail.com"/>
<property name="mailServerPassword" value="*************"/>
```

## engine.properties

```
engine.email.enabled=true
engine.email.host="smtp.gmail.com"

email.port=465

email.useCredentials=true

email.username=myadress@gmail.com
email.password=*********
email.ssl=true
email.tls=false

email.base.url=http://localhost:8080/activiti-app

email.from.default=myadress@gmail.com

email.from.default.name=myname
```

The error I get this error 500

```
{
"message": "Internal server error",
"exception": "Could not send e-mail in execution 20001"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gmail don't allow apps and devices that use less secure sign-in technology to access your account. You should turn on "allow less secure access your account" and test your mail task, if it is OK to send mail that is the issue, but be careful about what you are doing.