Issues with Mail Task Configuration in Activiti 6
I am new to Activiti, and I'm trying to use a mail task but it fails.
I did the same as the person who ask this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/53702268/2796306
and I use Gmail app password, not my actual password, since Gmail don't allow users to turn on "allow less secure access your account" anymore. Also, Beginning September 30, 2024: third-party apps that use only a password to access Google Accounts and Google Sync will no longer be supported.
I use Gmail app password and hope that it could make the mail task work, but it didn't.
In logs file, the error that occured was
24-Oct-2024 00:39:01.088 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [appDispatcher] in context with path [/activiti-app] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Could not send e-mail in execution 40011] with root cause     java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect  

Can someone please show me what I did wrong and how to fix it.
Best regards,
Ngoc.

Default Alfresco action use basic auth. It could be issue as you write with gmail. Easiest way to test it is just use some other mail platform. If that will work, then you have to write own mail action that use oAuth.
